# How to export clean SVGs using Sketch Plugin without mask or overrides. Sketch 49.3

Tags: svg, sketchapp

When I export the MSSymbolInstances as SVG I always get this line in the SVG code.

```
<g id="????/Fill/Gray-3" mask="url(#mask-2)" fill="#6A6A78">
```

It is not until that I edit the fill above manually and change "#1D1F20" to "none", can I use the SVG in my program. Is there any way to export the SVG without this particular fill or mask.

I have tried several approaches for this :-

1. Loop through all the layers and if it is a mssymbolinstance then export using the new sketch API sketch.export(layer, options).. This does not work.
2. Tried to duplicate a layer convert it to a group and then used group.export like what follows:

   var duplicates = layers[j].duplicate();
   var group = duplicates.detachByReplacingWithGroup();
   group = new sketch.Group(group);
   group.export({
   "formats": "svg",
   output : outputPath,
   //'use-id-for-name' : true,
   });
   group.remove();

This also does not work as the output SVGs all have the mask with some fill color overrides.

3. This approach is the same as 2. Here I just do not duplicate the layer before converting it into a group and exporting, however this has other downfalls.
   -> first of all it removes the symbol instances and thus the sketch document is changed.
   -> Secondly, I have to run it multiple times and often throws the error regarding 
   -[NSNull name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fffa6e3ecc0

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the npm package I made called [svgood](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgood). It removes *defs* and *g* (which tend to harbour the *mask*s) elements and floats the *path* element to the top level of the *svg*. I have some plans for making it more useful but let me know if I can add something that would make it better for your use case.